# In Matlab, I want to search 4 strings( str1, str2,str3, str4) in a txt file.

Tags: matlab, search

In Matlab, I want to search 4 strings( str1, str2,str3, str4) in a txt file. I know how to search only one string, but I dont want to search four times for each one. I think there must be a way that I can search only once but get the four strings.

Comment: Not that I know of.  If you want to search for four completely different strings, then you need to search four times.  However, if your strings follow a pattern... say they're off by a couple of characters, then perhaps it's possible.... but I can't think of any other way than to repeat the search four times.

Comment: Maybe you could create a regexp that includes all four strings. Post your code so we can see how it could be modified

Comment: You might find [these three algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns) interesting.